# Pasar al siguiente al seleccionar una opción en formulario por pasos

Tags: html, jquery, formularios

Requiero su ayuda para saber de que manera puedo pasar de un paso a otro al seleccionar una opción sin necesidad de darle al botón de siguiente.

A continuación les muestro unas imágenes de lo que me refiero.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para pasar con el botón "siguiente" es este:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
    var navListItems = $('ul.setup-panel li a'),
        allWells = $('.setup-content');

    allWells.hide();

    navListItems.click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
            $item = $(this).closest('li');
        
        if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
            navListItems.closest('li').removeClass('active');
            $item.addClass('active');
            allWells.hide();
            $target.show();
        }
    });
    
    $('ul.setup-panel li.active a').trigger('click');
    
    // ESTRUCTURA PASO 2//
    $('#activate-step-2').on('click', function(e) {
        $('ul.setup-panel li:eq(1)').removeClass('disabled');
        $('ul.setup-panel li a[href="#step-2"]').trigger('click');
        $(this).remove();
    })    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- TAMAÑO PERRO -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="col-md-12 well setup-content text-center" id="step-1" style="display: block;">
                <h2> ESCOGE SU TAMAÑO</h2>
                 
        <div style="text-align: center;" class="form-group">
         <div class="cc-selector">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <input checked="checked" id="tamanoperro-0" name="tamanoperro" style="border: none;" type="radio" value="pequeno"> 
                <label class="drinkcard-cc perropequeno" for="tamanoperro-0"></label> 
                <p class="wow pulse price animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: pulse;">0 - 12 Kg</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="tamanoperro-1" name="tamanoperro" type="radio" value="mediano"> 
                <label class="drinkcard-cc perromediano" style="height: 160px;" for="tamanoperro-1"></label>
                <p class="wow pulse price animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: pulse;">12 - 35 Kg</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                <input id="tamanoperro-2" name="tamanoperro" type="radio" value="grande"> 
                <label class="drinkcard-cc perrogrande" style="height: 200px;" for="tamanoperro-2"></label>
                <p class="wow pulse price animated" style="visibility: visible; animation-name: pulse;">35 o más Kg</p>
                </div>
               
           </div>
          </div>
         </div>
                <button id="activate-step-2" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Siguiente</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Quedo atento a sus colaboraciones, dado que no se de que manera lo podría llevar a cabo.

De antemano muchas gracias.

Comment: De qué checkbox estás hablando? Ayudaría ver el código HTML para tener una mejor idea.

Comment: Ya actualizo la pregunta para mostrarte.. son de radios

Answer (score 2):

Si ya todo lo anterior esta funcionando, entonces solo debes agregarle los eventos de pasar al siguiente a los checkbox.

Por ejemplo para el primero, como los checkbox tienen nombre `tamanoperro`, debes pasarle la función que tenias para `#activate-step-2` así:

```
    $('input[name="tamanoperro"]').on('click', function(e) {
        $('ul.setup-panel li:eq(1)').removeClass('disabled');
        $('ul.setup-panel li a[href="#step-2"]').trigger('click');
        $(this).remove();
    })
```

Tendras que hacerlo de igual forma para los siguientes checkbox con sus respectivos `#activate-step`.

Espero sea lo que buscas, saludos.

Comment: Justo lo que necesitaba, muchas gracias y que pena por la demora.